# Why does an `if statement` in R get evaluated without a logical condition?

Tags: r

I noticed that if I pass any number except 0 as an argument to an `if statement`, the code inside the `if statement` compiles. I am confused why this is happening! I understand that R internally recognizes 0 as FALSE and the statement inside the `if condition` is not evaluated, which makes sense, but why is it getting evaluated for other numbers?

```r
if(5) {
5 * 5
}
```

I had expected that I will get an error, but the code compiles and I get 25 as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `if`help page, `if` expects:

> A length-one logical vector  ... Other types are coerced to logical if possible, ignoring any class

So basically it does

```
as.logical(5)
# [1] TRUE
```

and since it's `5 != 0`, that's TRUE

```
as.logical(0)
# [1] FALSE
```

it's pretty common in languages for any number that's not 0 to be interpreted as "true"

Comment: Now it makes sense! But do you know why interpreting numbers beside 0 as "true" a case for many languages, like you pointed? I am just curious!

Comment: @Ashirwad Looks like that question has been asked here: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/198284/why-is-0-false

Comment: It looks like there has been a thorough discussion on this. Thanks for pointing me to this resource!